# Handling Very Large JSON Dataset?

Tags: json, performance

I have a scenario wherein frontend app makes a call to backend DB (APP -> API Gateway -> SpringBoot -> DB) with a JSON request. Backend returns a very large dataset (>50000 rows) in response sizing ~10 MB.

My frontend app is highly responsive and mission critical, we are seeing performance issues; frontend where app is not responding or timing-out. What can be best design to resolve this issue condering

1. DB query cant be normalized any further.
2. SpringBoot code has has cache builtin.
3. No data can be left behind due to intrinsic nature
4. No multiple calls can be made as data is needed is first call itself
5. Can any cache be built in-between frontend and backend?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your frontend actually do with the 50,000 rows? And what kind of data is it?

Comment: Is it a lookup or a search query which is returning 50k results

Comment: Its part of financial logic built for real-time transactions. While actual data is DB captive, it works as a unit only when requested in a complete set ; requested by frontend and queried by backend.We are bound not to make another call.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this is a generated report from a search. If this data needs to be associated with each other, I'd assign the search an id and restore the results on the server. Then pull the data for this id as needed on the frontend. You should never have to send 50,000 rows to the client in one go... Paginate the data and pull as needed if you have to. If you don't want to paginate, how much data can they display on a single screen? You can pull more data from the server based on where they scroll on the page. You should only need to return the count of the rows to the frontend, and maybe 100 rows of data. This would allow you to show a scrollbar with the right height. When they scroll to a certain position within the data, you can pull the corresponding offset from the server for that particular search id. Even if you could return all 50,000+ rows in one go, it doesn't sound very friendly to the end user's device to have to load that kind of memory for a functional page.
This is a sign of a flawed frontend that should be redone.

Answer (score 0):

10mb is huge and can be inconsiderate to your users especially if there's a high probability of mobile use.

If possible, it would be best to collect this data on the backend, probably put it onto disk, and then provide only the necessary data to the frontend as it's needed. As the map needs more data, you would make further calls to the backend.

If this isn't possible, you could load this data with the client-side bundle. If the data doesn't update too frequently, you can even cache it on the frontend. This would at least prevent the user from needing to fetch it repeatedly.